# Android Studio - Java - MediaPlayer sound effects sometimes not working

Tags: java, android, audio

I have the following set up and when I click certain images, it will play the sound effect. However, sometimes it doesn't play and I have an error output.

```
MediaPlayer soundFireball = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fireball)
```

This is under my event: `soundFireball.start();`

Sometimes it plays fine, sometimes I get the below error. It seems to be somewhat random; sometimes it plays once, then errors, sometimes it plays a few times (per event).

Any help whatsoever is greatly appreciated! :)

```
E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483646)
error (1, -2147483646)
E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483646)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483646)
I/chatty: uid=10093(net.androidbootcamp.rpgbattlesimulator) identical 1 line
E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483646)
E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483646)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483646)
```

Comment: ** Also, the fireball.wav is 259 KB

Comment: I solved it. Apparently I was making multiple MediaPlayer and recently found out that it is not good.

Thanks, stackoverflow